# saving xlsm with yesterday's date in folder path

Tags: excel, vba, xlsm

Looking for a quick heads up on the syntax issues here.

Goal:  Save an XLSM file with yesterday's date in a specific folder path.  Unfortunately this isn't working.  Does anyone see anything obviously wrong here?

```
Sub Ties()
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Test\Running" & Format(Now() – 1, “DD-MM-YYYY”) & ".xlsm"


End Sub
```

Comment: I think your `-` (dash) is actually an `—` (em-dash). Also you have smart quotes in the format they should be straight quotes

Comment: The code looks fine to me, provided the path is correct. How is it not working for you? The only thing that might be a problem is the missing file format argument -  FileFormat:= xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled.

Comment: Note that *"isn't working"* is a completely useless error description. And for the sake of Window's sorting algorithm I highly recommend to change the date format to the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format `YYYY-MM-DD` or you will end up with a very oddly sorted file list in your disk. Also see [https://xkcd.com/1179/](https://xkcd.com/1179/)

Comment: Yikes good call on the emdash, it's now actually working.  The only other item that's off is the formatting of the date is numerical value 44292, any fast fixes for that?  I think once we tick that off, we can mark this as solved.

Comment: replace the smart quotes in `“DD-MM-YYYY”` with straigth ones `"DD-MM-YYYY"` or your format function does not work as intended.